# IIS missing New Web Site option

Tags: iis

I've got IIS 5.1 running on my machine with one Web Site (Default Web Site) containing a few virtual directories.  I've got one virtual directory running an ASP.net site and it's working fine.  I tried to set up another virtual directory to run a classic asp site, but I guess you're not supposed to be able to do that.  So I was going to set up a separate web site to run it under, but I can't find the option to do this.  I looked around online and it appears that I should have an option when I right-click on the Web Sites folder to create a new web site, but this is absent.  The only options in that context menu are "Refresh", "Properties" and "Menu".  I can't find the "New Web Site" option anywhere.

Does anyone know why this might be?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

The issue was I didn't have NTFS permissions set for the website's directory, so it was giving me a no access error. I thought this was to do with IIS as apparently sometimes incorrect settings in IIS can cause this error.  Apparently not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIS 5.1 can only host 1 website.

I frequently used virtual directories on my WinXP box to separate multiple sites during development and had no problems.

Comment: I have multiple virtual directories running on that site. I think what it's not allowing me to do is have a single web site using classic and .net -- can you confirm or deny this?  Are you saying that only having one Web Site is a limitation of version 5?

Comment: To be clear, IIS 5.1 (Windows XP) has a limitation of 1 website. IIS 5 (Server 2000) does not. You can run classic sites and .net sites side-by-side in different virtual directories.

Comment: I'm running IIS 6.0 on XP Pro 64bit.  The "new website" context menu item is missing for me too.

Comment: @Robert, while 64bit XP does indeed have IIS6, sadly, it also has the same 1 website limitation